# Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<{}>'

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angularfire

I am working with Angular7, Angularfire2 5.1.0 and Firebase 5.5.8. After code a demo app I had the error:

> "ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(13,5): error TS2322: Type
> '(events?: ChildEvent[]) => Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to
> type 'AngularFireList<{}>'.   Property 'query' is missing in type
> '(events?: ChildEvent[]) => Observable<{}[]>'."

[image: error screen]

Comment: you should copy/paste your code and not take a picture

Comment: More constructive comment : you must subscribe to your AngularFireList

Answer (score 0):

I said you must subscribe. Here is an example:

```
this.db.list('/customers').valueChanges().subscribe((datas) => { console.log("datas", datas) },(err)=>{ console.log("probleme : ", err) });
```

Comment: Hi Christophe Gudlake. Thank you for your help. I am new in angular and I don't know yet how work fine with this technology. Could you help me adding an example using my code please? Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question with a code snippet and I will. But I wint start from your screen shot